# Redirect to the same node for edit after node creation/edit

Tags: php, drupal-8, hook-form-alter, form-alter

Drupal8 takes users to the node detailed page after creation or edit. I would like to modify the behaviour and redirect it to the node editing page.

I researched in Google and found that I should use HOOK_form_alter method in the administration theme to apply the redirect.

I have checked the following StackOverflow answer but no success. 
[How can I redirect a Drupal user after they create new content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227302/how-can-i-redirect-a-drupal-user-after-they-create-new-content)

```
//hook_form_alter
function adminimal_theme_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id == 'node_article_edit_form' || $form_id == 'node_article_form' && $form_state->isMethodType('POST')) {

    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'] = 'seven_redirect_handler';

  }
}

function seven_redirect_handler($form, &$form_state) {
  $response = new TrustedRedirectResponse('/node/1');
  $form_state->setResponse($response);
}
```

For some reasons, it does not work. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can use Rules module [https://www.drupal.org/project/rules]

Comment: link is broken.

Comment: You can use Rules module https://www.drupal.org/project/rules